# Fitting a log link with a normal distribution in GEE

Tags: r

I have a data similar to the following and I wanted to fit an exchangeable correlation matrix with normal variance distribution with a log link.

```
x <- data.frame(id=rep(1:20, each=3), events=sample(0:12,60, replace = T), 
                sport=sample(0:1,30, replace = T), sex=rep(c("M","F"), each=30))

library(gee)
gee(events ~ sport + sex, id=id, data = x,
                      corstr = "exchangeable", family = gaussian(link="log"))
```

When trying to fit this using the `gee` or `geeglm` functions in R, I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(family$initialize) : cannot find valid starting values: please specify some
```

This is most likely because I have `0`s in my outcome; and I read I have to specify something with either `start` or `offset`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using a "log" link with a gaussian distribution?

Comment: I am doing this for a class project where it was explicitly asked. I am aware Stata does it with no issues, and R does too when the outcome contains no 0s. i was wondering if there is a way around that.

Comment: Ok. So supply a vector of starting values `b`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a vector of starting values, with appropriate length. An initial guess could be found from running a similar model but using a default "identity" link for the gaussian distribution.

```
library(gee)
gee0 <- gee(events ~ sport + sex, id=id, data = x,
                      corstr = "exchangeable", family = gaussian))
___
(Intercept)       sport        sexM 
   5.797436   -1.230769    1.866667
```

So try these for starters. According to the **documentation**, the starting values can be specified using the `b` argument.

```
gee1 <- gee(events ~ sport + sex ,id=id, data = x, b=coef(gee0),
            corstr = "exchangeable", family = gaussian("log"))
summary(gee1)
```

---

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Naive S.E.   Naive z Robust S.E.  Robust z
(Intercept)  1.7360218  0.1481879 11.715004   0.1503372 11.547521
sport       -0.2060653  0.1575038 -1.308320   0.1546603 -1.332374
sexM         0.3191439  0.1589250  2.008141   0.1530178  2.085665
```